# Is it possible to compute large matrix multiplication, using Renderscript?

Tags: android, renderscript

I need to compute matrix(large scale) multiplication quickly on Android.

Is it possible to compute large matrix multiplication, using Renderscript?

I heard that we can do GPGPU using Renderscript on Android

However, I cannot find any example for large matrix multiplication.

Actually, I tried to do matrix multiplication, using rsMatrixMultiply function, but it just multiply the 4x4 matrix with a vector of size 3.

I have no idea to multiply 'matrics of arbitrary size'.
If it is possible, can you introduce some examples?

Comment: Please start doing some code by yourself , then if you got stucked with some exact issue, then someone will be able to  help you. Refer this link for asking proper questions 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask